# How to exclude white spaces while search

Tags: typescript

In Angular2+ I wrote a pipe for searching through an array, which is working fine. but I want to exclude the white spaces in the array.

My current PIPE

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'arraySearch'
})

export class ArraySearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!args) { return value; }
    return value.filter(item => this.checkValues(item, args));
  }

  checkValues(item, args) {
    const value = Object.keys(item).map(k => item[k]);
    return String(value).indexOf(args) > -1;
  }

}
```

This piece of code searches for terms with exact terms. How to exclude spaces in array items and search?

Thanks.

Comment: White space in array Item or just `' '`?

Comment: any spaces in array item @TheDictator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
checkValues(item, args) {
    const value = Object.keys(item).map(k => item[k]);
    return String(value).replace(/ /g,"").indexOf(args) > -1;
 }
```